# /dev/ttyS0 in lxc container

Tags: lxc, device

How to set up lxc to get /dev/ttyS0 in lxc container.

I add

```
# /dev/ttyS0
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 4:64 rwm
```

into config

but nothing works -

If I add manually mknod in running container everything works until reboot - after reboot device ttyS0 disappears